# Insert an empty line without indentation

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm writing some python and I would like to insert an empty line without any indentation e.g. Pressing Enter or Enter+cmd

```
if foo == "foo":
    foo.bar()
    foo.bar()
    foo.bar()
    # cursor is here 
    foo.baz()
    foo.baz()
    foo.baz()
    foo.baz()
```

I'd like it to be

```
if foo == "foo":
    foo.bar()
    foo.bar()
    foo.bar()
# cursor is here 
    foo.baz()
    foo.baz()
    foo.baz()
    foo.baz()
```

I believe this is similar to Visual Studio `CTRL + Enter`

In sublime I have created a command

```
[
    {
        "args":
        {
            "characters": "\n"
        },
        "command": "insert"
    },
    {
        "args":
        {
            "to": "hardbol"
        },
        "command": "move_to"
    },
    {
        "args":
        {
            "file": "res://Packages/Default/Delete to Hard EOL.sublime-macro"
        },
        "command": "run_macro_file"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is a combination of two commands:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> `editor.action.insertLineAfter`
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> `editor.action.trimTrailingWhitespace`

There is a [feature request for macro like keybindings](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/871). In the meantime you can try [the macros extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros), use the shortcuts one after another, or...

Add the following to your keybindings.json file, which essentially provides a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> shortcut that does exactly what you need.

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+m",
        "command": "editor.action.trimTrailingWhitespace",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Python uses line indention, rather than brackets, to create a block of code.  The code presented above can be done in literally any text editor, but will throw an exception, because Python will be expecting instructions.

If your intent is to have an empty statement that does nothing, then try:

```
if foo == 'foo':
     pass
```

Pass tells the system explicitly to continue on without doing anything.

If you are looking to do this for stylistic reasons, then you are barking up the wrong tree.  In order to function Python MUST have the next line after an if statement be indented.  When the indentation goes away, that tells python that it's done with that block and leaves the if statement.

Comment: There are couple reasons to use this e.g. I have an inline html inside python or I'd like to add some empty lines for readability

Comment: If that is the case, still tab out to the normal place, but put no text after it.

This way you have what looks like a blank line, but Python still has that indentation to recognize that it's still part of the block.

Comment: Which editor are you using?  That may be what I am misunderstanding.  It may be editor specific.